# Decimal Format Issue Java

Tags: java

I wrote a program and I can't figure out how i should do the decimal format? I thought i was doing it right, apparently i can't do decimal format correctly. Can, someone help me with the decimal format?

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;
public class Mean {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[]x = new double[10];
            int i;
            for(i = 0;i < 10; i++){
                x[i] = s.nextDouble();
            }
            double mean = mean(x, i);
            double deviation = var(x);
            System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
            System.out.println("The standard deviation is " + deviation);
    }
public static double sum(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static double mean(double[]x, double i){
        if (x.length == 0) return Double.NaN;
        double sum = sum(x);
        return sum / x.length;
    }
    public static double var(double[] x) {
        if (x.length == 0) return Double.NaN;
        double avg = mean(x, 10);
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            sum += (x[i] - avg) * (x[i] - avg);
        }
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        return sum / myFormatter.format(Math.sqrt(x.length - 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: it depends how you want your decimal format to be looking like ?

Comment: Show you're desired output, current output, and input

Comment: (what i want) Kinda like this: 1,234.56 (rounds off after 2nd decimal number).

(what i get) Error!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to format your double(s)... I also had to update you method `var` -

```
public static String formatDouble(double in) {
  DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(
      "#,##0.00");
  return myFormatter.format(in);
}

public static double var(double[] x) {
  if (x.length == 0)
    return Double.NaN;
  double avg = mean(x);
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    sum += (x[i] - avg) * (x[i] - avg);
  }
  return sum / Math.sqrt(x.length - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  double[] x = new double[] {
    2000.20, 1000.10, 3000.30, 4000.40,5000.50,
    6000.60,7000,70,8000.80,9000.90
  };
  double mean = mean(x);
  double deviation = var(x);
  System.out.println("The mean is "
      + formatDouble(mean));
  System.out.println("The standard deviation is "
      + formatDouble(deviation));
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, i got a compilation error? Also, the user is supposed to input the numbers...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the formatter return a String. you should return a String in the metod signature

```
public static String var(double[] x)
```

Also this line

```
return sum / myFormatter.format(Math.sqrt(x.length - 1));
```

Will not work if you are to return a String. You should do the calculations first, and then format it. Then return the formatted number

**Edit:** Try this, see if it works

```
public static String var(double[] x) {
    if (x.length == 0) 
        return null;

    double avg = mean(x, 10);
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sum += (x[i] - avg) * (x[i] - avg);
    }
    DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
    double result = sum / Math.sqrt(x.length - 1);

    return myFormatter.format(result);

}
```

Then where you have this `double deviation = var(x);` replace it with `String deviation = var(x);`

**Edit 2:** complete code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;
public class Mean {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[]x = new double[10];
            int i;
            for(i = 0;i < 10; i++){
                x[i] = s.nextDouble();
            }
            double mean = mean(x, i);
            String deviation = var(x);                  // changed to String
            System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
            System.out.println("The standard deviation is " + deviation);
    }
public static double sum(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static double mean(double[]x, double i){
        if (x.length == 0) return Double.NaN;
        double sum = sum(x);
        return sum / x.length;
    }
    public static String var(double[] x) {         // changed return
        if (x.length == 0) 
            return null;

        double avg = mean(x, 10);
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            sum += (x[i] - avg) * (x[i] - avg);
        }
        DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        double result = sum / Math.sqrt(x.length - 1);

        return myFormatter.format(result);

    }
}
```

**Update:** correct standard deviation formula

```
double result = Math.sqrt(sum / (x.length - 1));

                          ^^
```

Comment: Where does that go exactly? I am not sure which public static that i should replace?

Comment: This may be a ridiculous question, but may you do it for me? I don't understand it very well... :(

Comment: I still get errors? May you put that on my code because i believe i am placing it in the wrong place... :(

Comment: Take a look at my **Edit 2**. Shows all the fixes. Assuming all calculations are correct, I think the program should run now. I haven't tried to run it myself

Comment: Oh thanks! It works so far but the problem is that it doesn't go into decimal format?

Comment: What do you input? Let me test it

Comment: The code I have above works fine. You need to enter a number, then hit enter. You need to repeat that 10 times. You can't write them all on the same line

Comment: Well, here is an error log: 
Log 1
On Line 1 its column 15
Line 1 Wrong: The mean is 30278.519905400004
Line 1 Right: The mean is 30,278.52 
Log 2
On Line 1 its column 14
Line 1 Wrong: The mean is 7609.71691
Line 1 Right: The mean is 7,609.72 

Is there something that I was supposed to do that I missed?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: You need to hit enter after every number input. They can't be on the same line. It works perfectly for me when I enter all tens `The mean is 10.0
The standard deviation is 0.00`

Comment: Well lets say instead of getting 7,721.85 i get 7721.8567

Comment: What numbers are you inputting? Let me try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43689/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-wumbo)

Comment: See my **Update**. That should solve your problem. Please don't forget to accept _and_ /or up-vote answers that solve your problem. Emphasis on the _and_. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the double at the time of print.If you tried at var() function and then assign with double deviation then it will give numberformatException due to special character that returns by Var().You can run this code It will give you the output.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[]x = new double[10];
            int i;
            for(i = 0;i < 2; i++){
                x[i] = s.nextDouble();
            }
            double mean = mean(x, i);
            double deviation = var(x);
            DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
            System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
            System.out.println("The standard deviation is " +myFormatter.format(deviation));
        }
        public static double sum(double[] a) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                sum += a[i];
            }
            return sum;
        }
        public static double mean(double[]x, double i){
            if (x.length == 0) return Double.NaN;
            double sum = sum(x);
            return sum / x.length;
        }
        public static double var(double[] x) {
            if (x.length == 0) return Double.NaN;
            double avg = mean(x, 10);
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                sum += (x[i] - avg) * (x[i] - avg);
            }
            return sum / Math.sqrt(x.length - 1);
        }
```